# Create relationship between DOM Nodes

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to scrape an e-commerce like site, where I need to establish a relationship between the Title of a listing and its description. The problem is that I do not know how to reliably do so, because some listings have a description - some don't. As a result I cannot reliably use a for loop in associating a title with a description. Could you please offer your suggestions ?

This is how I was thinking , but it doesnt work reliably:

```
const allTitles= document.querySelectorAll(".title");
const arrayOfTitlesAndDescription= allTitles.map((title,index) => { title :document.querySelectAll(".description")[index] } )
```

Thank you very much !

[This image would help you understand better , if the question is unclear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIt67.png)

EDIT:

```
const allCards= document.querySelectorAll(".card");
/// also tried with allCards directly
Array.from(allCards).forEach(card => card.querySelector(".description"));
/// This works, but I don't know how to tell which .card is which
document.querySelectorAll(".card").querySelector(".description")
```

Comment: Is the `.title` and `.description` of each listing wrapped in an element. If so, you can loop through all those type of elements and get the `.title` and `.description` child elements.

Comment: @Titus Thank you very much for your reply ! Yes , they probably are. I will check your suggestion right now. If I understand it correctly, say the parent class is card , then I will loop through `document.querySelectAll(".card")` and then access title and description as `document.querySelectAll(".card.title") ` ?

Comment: Something like that. This is the correct approach `[...document.querySelectAll(".card")].map(card => ({ title: card.querySelector('.title'), description: card.querySelector('.description') }))`. You should use `querySelector(...)` for the child elements and you should call that on the `.card` element not on `document`.

Comment: @Titus wow ! Didnt know that , thanks a lot !

Comment: @Titus Do I have to transform all the nodes array I loop through ? Because when I do the `querySelector(...)` inside the .map it is always undefined

Comment: @Titus I found it ! Seems like you have to stack these queries on the document (or the node). Thank you again !

Comment: Great. I'm glad I could help. Also, you should probably filter the array before mapping it, something like `[...document.querySelectAll(".card")].filter(card => (card.querySelector('.title') && card.querySelector('.description'))).map(...)`

Comment: @Titus I've been trying for a bit and still can't figure it out ... I have edited to reflect this. Could you please let me know what Im doing wrong ? Thank you so much !

Comment: Try this: `const results = [...document.querySelectAll(".card")].map(card => ({ title: card.querySelector('.title'), description: card.querySelector('.description') })).map(({ title, description }) => ({ title: title && title.textContent, description: description && description.textContent }))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for some div tag that encloses both `.title` and `.description` and for  each of such tag search weather its children have any description or not.

Comment: How do I search if the tag has these children ? For example the class `.card`

Comment: you can iterate all cards just the way you iterated over you title.

Comment: It seems like it doesnt work. I have edited the question with how I do it. Could you please take a look ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-forest-cp5zj?file=/src/index.js have a look at the sandbox.